# SQL Server GROUPING and DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi i have very complicated select statement made by a former employee here in our company
What it does is return all the list of jobs applied to by an applicant.
The query is working fine except that i need to get only unique Jobs applied. I'm having trouble with DISTINCT or GROUP BY.
The duplicates happen because the table that relates the Jobs and the Applicant has duplicates which i cant do anything about. So can anyone help me figure this out?
PS: Please don't blame for the Query structure its not mine. Thanks!

```
         SELECT 
                J.JobsID, 
                J.JobsHeader, 
                I.IndustryName,
                J.JobDescription, 
                J.JobBreif, 
                J.JobRequirement, 
                J.JobLocation, 
                (SELECT CASE WHEN J.HideSalary = 1 THEN 'hidden' ELSE J.Salary END) AS 'Salary',
                J.HideSalary, 
                (SELECT CASE WHEN J.HideCompanyName = 1 THEN 'hidden' ELSE COMP.CompanyName END) AS 'CompanyName',
                J.HideCompanyName, 
                J.CurrentStatus, 
                J.ExperienceInMonth, 
                J.ExperienceInYear, 
                Q.QualificationName, 
                J.HourID, 
                J.Age, 
            J.Gender, 
            L.CityName, 
            J.UAENationals, 
            J.SeniorExecutive, 
            J.StartDate, 
            J.EndDate, 
            S.SpecizationName, 
            CIRT.SpecizationName AS 'CirtificationName', 
            J.AvailType,
            J.CreatedOn, 
            J.CreatedBy, 
            J.ModifiedOn, 
            J.ModifiedBy,
            N.CountryName,
            --ETJA.CreatedOn AS 'AppliedOn',
            '12/01/2012' AS 'AppliedOn',
            ETJA.JobsId AS 'AppliedJobId'


        FROM dbo.EmployeeToJobsApplied ETJA 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Jobs J ON J.JobsID = ETJA.JobsId
        INNER JOIN dbo.Employers COMP ON J.CompanyID = COMP.EmployerId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Experience E ON J.ExperienceInYear = E.ExperienceID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Industry I ON J.JobIndustryId = I.IndustryID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Location L ON J.LocationID = L.CityId
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Qualification Q  ON J.QualificationID = Q.QualificationID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Nation N ON J.CountryID = N.CountryID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Specization S  ON J.SpecilizationId = S.SpecizationID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Specization CIRT ON J.CirtificationId  = CIRT.SpecizationID
        WHERE ETJA.Applied = 1 AND ETJA.EmployeeId=1
```

Comment: Well you don't need to use GROUPing because you're not using any aggregate functions (sum, count etc).  So if you include the DISTINCT keyword, which columns are returning different values such that you get duplicate Jobs? Do you really need all those tables and all those values returned?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `DISTINCT` to the existing query but I suspect there are several columns being selected that will always be unique (e.g., CreatedOn, ModifiedOn). So, it's not likely to help.

You'll have to create a query that just returns a subset of the columns that you currently have. Start with the bare minimum and verify it gives you the correct jobs list. Then start adding the additional columns -- if it stops returning distinct jobs, then you won't be able to use that column in this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    J.JobsID,
    J.JobsHeader 
FROM dbo.EmployeeToJobsApplied ETJA 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Jobs J ON J.JobsID = ETJA.JobsId
WHERE ETJA.Applied = 1 AND ETJA.EmployeeId=1
```